# FB.api POST to a group is returning GET 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, post, get

I know this must be a simple thing, but for the life of me I cannot find an answer by examining my code nor using Google to get help with possible causes!

### Here is a picture of my table:

(picture would go here, but apparently I have to have at least 10 reputation to post images?)

Description of picture instead: a simple HTML Table with a Header row and as many following rows as Facebook Groups to which I belong. There are 5 columns: Icon, Name, Email, ID, and a column for a button to remove that particular row.

The table structure and data is dynamically built with a JavaScript function.

### Here is my JavaScript function that forms and processes the call to the FB.api:

```
function postMessage() {
groupsTbl = document.getElementById("groupsTbl");
msgSubject = document.getElementById("msgSubject");
msgBody = document.getElementById("msgBody");
msgPic = document.getElementById("msgPic");

FB.getLoginStatus(
    function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            for (var i = 1; i < groupsTbl.rows.length; i++) {
                row = groupsTbl.rows[i].cells;                  
                /* make the API call */
                FB.api(
                    "/" + row[3].innerHTML + "/feed",
                    "POST",
                    { "object": { "message": "this is a test" } },
                    function (response) {
                        if (response && !response.error) {
                            console.log(response);/* handle the result */
                        }
                        else
                            console.log(response);/* handle the result */
                    }
                );
            }
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
        // but has not authenticated your app
        } else {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
        }
    }
);
}
```

### And here is the result.

As you can see from the top of the screenshot, the IDs are retrieved successfully and printed to the Console for debug purposes. The GET appears to have the IDs correctly, but obviously something went wrong!

(picture would go here, but apparently I have to have at least 10 reputation to post images?)

Description of image instead:

```
126566634108032 (index):123
GET https://graph.facebook.com/157375201005164/feed?access_token=CAAVK9GATPtMBA…&object=%7B%22message%22%3A%22this%20is%20a%20test%22%7D&pretty=0&sdk=joey 500 (Internal Server Error) debug.js:6245
Object {error: Object}
error: Object
message: "unknown error"
type: "http"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api/#examples There's a `Example: Publish a status message to the current user's feed`:

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

Transferred to you code, this would yield in

```
FB.api(
    "/me/feed",
    "POST",
    { message: "this is a test" },
    function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
        else
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.error));
    }
;
```

Comment: Wow! That does work! I can post messages now. I was also running into a problem adding the link as per the API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/feed). But now that works too!!

    FB.api('/' + row[3].innerHTML + '/feed', 'post', { message: msgBody.value, link: msgPic.value }, function (response) { if (response && !response.error) { console.log(response); } else console.log(response); });